# Recently ordered, change order

Tags: magento2, sidebar

the sidebar "recently ordered" show last order, but I don't get the order of product.

For example, here I have three products: `C...` `M...` `S...` (it's in french, so I show only the first letter).

The sidebar show in this order:
`S`
`C`
`M`

Why, and how I can change it ?I already search, but it's difficult to find this specific question.

I want to have the sidebar show recently order products order by name, so result would be:

`C` `M` `S`

I can try to explain it better if you don't understand.

Edit : I find the phtml file at :

> C:/wamp64/www/market-eurecia/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml

But i don't know how it work, i find the databind with the foreach, but don't know how to change the order.

Comment: Means you need to change order of that product which put in single order?

Comment: I need to order them by name, sorry i edit the post

Comment: you need identify phtml file which called there and make sorting there.

Comment: hi thanks, i find it on :
C:/wamp64/www/market-eurecia/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml
But i don't know where i need to change something to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two possible ways to do this, either with js or with php

The file **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml** pulls the data (**data-bind="scope: 'lastOrderedItems'"**) from a knockout view **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/web/js/view/last-ordered-items.js**

Using the js approach, in the knockout view we can see:

```
this.lastOrderedItems = customerData.get('last-ordered-items');

for (item in this.lastOrderedItems.items) {
    if (item['is_saleable']) {
        isShowAddToCart = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

So there we could sort the **this.lastOrderedItems** to meet our needs

To use the php approach we'd have to look at the dataProvider which we can see defined in the di.xml:

```
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="last-ordered-items" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\CustomerData\LastOrderedItems</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

So when we check the file **vendor/magento/module-sales/CustomerData/LastOrderedItems.php** we can see an order collection loaded with a sort definition:

```
$orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()])
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
    ->setPage(1, 1);
```

It's recommended to override/extend core files, so to do any of those changes you would create a custom module